# wordpress: Allow sending email to only a particular domain

Tags: wordpress, smtp

WordPress Question: It would be great help if someone could help me with this:
I want to restrict ‘To’ field to have only a few particular domains for security reason, e.g., outgoing emails will be allowed if those are sent to only @domain1.com and @domain2.com; all other emails will be blocked.

Will I have to add any filter to wp_mail function? Any lead will be helpful as I am a newbie to WordPress programming :). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the mail with the function wp_mail you have to check with a preg_match if the email address is matching your domains

use this kind of pattern (this example allow mail with the domains : domain.com and domain2.com)
https://www.regextester.com/94044 
if the preg_match return true then send the mail else throw an error